# ChunkedOutput response from Jersey REST services

Tags: jersey, streaming, response

I am writing Jersey REST services on tomcat. REST service talks to Database and send back the data to REST client. I want to stream the data back to client so my tomcat server does not crash due to the huge response from Database as I dont know what could be the database response size. I chose to go with chunkedoutput from jersey. (please note , i have put test methods to mimic the actual methods) Below is the server side code snipped ,

```java
@GET
@Path("numbers")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ChunkedOutput<TestMessage> sendChunkedOutput() {
    final ChunkedOutput<TestMessage> output = new ChunkedOutput<TestMessage>(TestMessage.class,",");

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("*** Writing the response in chunkedoutput");
                for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                    output.write(getNumber(i));
                }
                System.out.println("*** completed wiriting output to chunkedoutpu1234");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
    System.out.println("Thread is implemented and started ");
    return output;
}

public TestMessage getNumber(long l) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new TestMessage(l);
}
```

And below is the client code ,

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.property(ClientProperties.CHUNKED_ENCODING_SIZE, 100);
client.property(ClientProperties.REQUEST_ENTITY_PROCESSING, RequestEntityProcessing.CHUNKED);

Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8080/ChunkedServer/rest")
    .path("numbers").request()
    .property(ClientProperties.CHUNKED_ENCODING_SIZE, 100)
    .property(ClientProperties.REQUEST_ENTITY_PROCESSING, RequestEntityProcessing.CHUNKED)
    .get();

final ChunkedInput<String> input = response.readEntity(
    new GenericType<ChunkedInput<String>>() {}
);
String chunk;
while ((chunk = input.read()) != null) {
    System.out.println();
    if (chunk.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("null");
    } else {
        System.out.println("chunk: " + chunk);
    }
}
}
```

Unfortunately , even my server is taking time to send back the data to client, response is not sent in chunks. The complete response is sent only at once only.
Any reason why the chunked output is not sent to client ?

Answer (score 4):

As the [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html) tells us, that the `ChunkedInput` does not know how to distinguish chunks unless its being told, you need to add a custom `org.glassfish.jersey.client.ChunkParser` to your code or alternatively make sure the server-side uses the default `ChunkParser` `chunkDelimiter`.

**Documentation (11.2.2. Chunked input):**

> The ChunkedInput does not know how to distinguish chunks in the byte stream unless being told by the developer.
>
> In order to define custom chunks boundaries, the ChunkedInput offers possibility to register a ChunkParser which reads chunks from the input stream and separates them.
>
> Jersey provides several chunk parser implementation and you can implement your own parser to separate your chunks if you need.

Without declaring your own parser, Jersey uses the default parser that separates chunks based on presence of a `\r\n` delimiting character sequence

---

### Two possible options:

**1) Use custom chunkDelimiter**

As your are currently using `,` as server-side `chunkDelimiter` the client should look like:

```java
final ChunkedInput<String> input = response.readEntity(
    new GenericType<ChunkedInput<String>>() {}
);
input.setParser(ChunkedInput.createParser(","));
while ((chunk = input.read()) != null) {
    // [...]
```

**2) Use default chunkDelimiter**

Server side:

```java
final ChunkedOutput<String> output = new ChunkedOutput<String>(String.class, "\r\n");
```

**Note:** 
Jersey does not use the default `ChunkParser` `chunkDelimiter` within the `ChunkedOutput` constructor. Meaning ...

```java
final ChunkedOutput<String> output = new ChunkedOutput<String>(String.class);
```

... will not work, as the default will be set to a zero length delimter `(new byte[0])`

Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks a lot @zyexal . This was a great explanation!